# Adding/removing a component in C# by pressing a GUI.Button does not function right in Unity3d

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, unityscript, destroy

I'm having a difficult time trying to add and remove a js script as a component to a gameObject in C#, as I'm novice to Unity and coding.

I have a js that needs to be added in MainCamera in runtime, by click of a GUI.Button. This script has to be destroyed later with the same GUI.Button clicked.

I have managed to add the js script on the MainCamera in runtime with the following code snippet:

```
public Bearing addBearing; // "Bearing" is the js script and "addBearing the variable to    reference this

//some other codding
.
.
// Add and remove Bearing with this button
public bool addBearing;

void OnGUI(){
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10, 100, 100), "Bearing"))

addBearing= !addBearing;

if(addBearing){
addBearing  = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").gameObject.AddComponent<Bearing>();

}else{

GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").gameObject.GetComponent<Bearing>();

Destroy(GetComponent<Bearing>());
```

Problem is, that when I click back the "Bearing" GUI.Button, js script "Bearing" is not get destroyed as it should.

There is something missing in this code logic, but I'm not that experienced in coding C# to find a solution. So, can someone be kind enough to get me a helping hand with this code? It would be very much appreciated. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

instead of adding and destroying, why don't you use

GetComponent(Bearing).enabled = false; to disable and

GetComponent(Bearing).enabled = true;   to enable

Comment: Hello @Thilina Premasiri. I need to get the component destroyed cause, the "Bearing" is an accelerometer and compass script and mess up the "MainCamera" if it is attached even disabled. Do you happen to know how to destroy this component, as it is in my posted code snippet?

Comment: `else{

GameObject g=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").gameObject.GetComponent<Bearing>();

Destroy(g);`

modify your else part as in this snippet

Answer (score 2):

When you call `GetComponent<Bearing>()`, you are getting the `Bearing` component on the object within the current scope.  If you do not specify a scope, then it will look for a component on the GameObject that the script is attached to.  So instead of:

`Destroy(GetComponent<Bearing>());`

Instead, you want:

`Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Bearing>());`

`GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` establishes the scope, then `GetComponent<Bearing>` gets a reference to the `Bearing` component on whatever scope was established before it.  So combining those two will get you a `Bearing` component from the Main Camera, which is passed into the Destroy function which destroys it.